# get entity value at client side in MS CRM (javascript)

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm

Let say I have the entity Branches, which have vale a,b,c,d,e... I want to show these value on another entity's New form as picklist field. what have to do. Is need to write the javascript so that I can get the value of Branch entity and assign to picklist field in another entity. please i am new in MS CRM, guide me. please.

Answer (score 0):

This should help get you started:

http://danielcai.blogspot.com/2010/07/crm-web-service-toolkit-for-javascript.html

Perhaps an even easier way though - why not just add a relationship from your other entity to your Branch entity?  Then add the lookup to the other entity, and users will be able to choose the Branch (or even type it in).